# Android - Don't show more than 1 of each type of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

A lot of different kinds of `DialogFragment`s are used in our app, so I created a `BaseFragment` to factor out some of the common code. There is one constraint though: We should not show more than 1 instance of the same type of fragment at any given time (however, we *should* display both `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` if they occur simultaneously).

The code I currently have below does achieve this behavior, but I am not satisfied as it results in a lot of boilerplate in the child classes. Is there a more concise way to accomplish this?

#### BaseFragment

```
abstract class BaseFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun show(manager: FragmentManager, tag: String?) {
        if (!isShowing()) {
            setShowing(true)
            super.show(manager, tag)
        }
    }

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog)
        setShowing(false)
    }

    abstract fun isShowing(): Boolean

    abstract fun setShowing(isShowing: Boolean)

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

#### ChildFragment

```
class ChildFragment : BaseFragment() {

    companion object {
        private var sIsShowing = false
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): AlertDialog {
        // ...
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    }

    // ...

    override fun isShowing(): Boolean = sIsShowing

    override fun setShowing(isShowing: Boolean) { sIsShowing = isShowing }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by doing so:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun show(manager: FragmentManager, tag: String?) {
        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            super.show(manager, tag)
            manager.executePendingTransactions()
        }
    }
}
```

Just be careful to keep the `tag` the same between the same dialog classes. For example, all instances of `Dialog1` which extends `BaseFragment` should have the same `tag` which is different from the `tag` used in the other subclasses of `BaseFragment`.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but unfortunately it fails. Specifically, the `findFragmentByTag` returns `null` even when it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you provide a code for the cases in which it fails? How do you call the `show(..)` method?

Comment: If I do
`{ Fragment1().show(supportFragmentManager, Fragment1::class.java.simpleName); Fragment1().show(supportFragmentManager, Fragment1::class.java.simpleName) }`
in an activity, the fragment will show twice.

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out now, and say if it works.

Comment: `manager.executePendingTransactions()` seems to have done the trick! Thanks!